# How to prove the statement about the rank of a block matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be real matrices with the same number of rows. Prove that:

$$\mbox{rank} \begin{bmatrix} A & B\\ 2A & -5B\end{bmatrix} = \mbox{rank}(A) + \mbox{rank}(B)$$

---

I have no idea how to approach the problem. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Only same number of rows or dimension?

Comment: Only same number of rows

Comment: There are many ways you might have added context to this Question.  Presumably it is an exercise intended to reinforce learning of material recently or contiguously covered in a course or textbook, but your Readers have no way of knowing that unless you share the context.  "I have no idea how to approach the problem" would seem to imply you have no interest in learning the material and simply want someone to *give* you the *answer*, but I suspect you just didn't think enough about the problem before posting.  For example, one might do a smallish example, say a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract the double of the first block row from the second one, we get
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ 0&-7B}.
$$
Then divide the second block row by $-7$ to obtain
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ 0&B}.
$$
Finally, subtract the second block row from the first block row to obtain
$$
M=\pmatrix{A&0\\ 0&B}.
$$
If you can prove that $\operatorname{rank}(M)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$, then you are done, because the rank of a matrix is unaffected by elementary row operations.